# Missing Edit Options in SharePoint MySite Ribbon

Tags: 2010, ribbon

I am trying to do some heavy customisation to a SharePoint 2010 MySite. I have hit a bug with the SharePoint ribbon editing tools disapearing. When I reset the default mysite.master as masterpage and the default.aspx page as the homepage it still occurs. The 'bug', at least I think it's a bug, is that when I try to edit page the normal editing tools don't appear. I find that if you go to edit a web part then click to edit a page again then they appear again.

[image]

Had anybody noticed this functionality? Is it something I am doing wrong or is this default for MySites?

Thanks very much,

Dee

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a the same on mysite and resolved by following steps

1. central admin > Service applications > UPS service application > Permissions

   - Ensure the farm admin account has full control.
2. central admin > Service applications > UPS service application > Manage > Manage user permissions

   - Ensure "NT Authority\Authenticated Users" and "All Authenticated users" have all 3 permissions shown
3. My site > site settings > site permissions

   - Ensure "NT Authority\Authenticated Users" and "All Authenticated users" have read

The ribbon should show the page edit options on mysite pages.

Answer (score 0):

I Think you might have disabled the edit ribbon button on the site or you  might have set the ribbon to default browse rather than edit.Go through them once